# Xpath query to select node when attribute does not exist?

Tags: xpath, attributes

I want to select nodes for which a specific attribute does not exist. I've tried the Not() function, but it doesn't work. Is there a way for this?

Example:
The following Xpath query:

```
group/msg[not(@owner)]
```

Should retrieve the first node but not the 2nd one. However, both SketchPath (tool to test Xpath queries) and my C# code consider that the 2 nodes are ok.

```
<group>
    <msg id="EVENTDATA_CCFLOADED_XMLCONTEXT"  numericId="14026"  translate="False"  topicId="302"  status="translated" >
        <text>Context</text>
        <comment></comment>
    </msg>
    <msg id="EVENTDATA_CCFLOADED_XMLCONTEXT_HELP"  numericId="14027"  translate="False"  topicId="302"  status="translated"  owner="EVENTDATA_CCFLOADED_XMLCONTEXT" >
        <text>Provides the new data displayed in the Object.</text>
        <comment></comment>
    </msg>
</group>
```

---

In fact the Not() function works correctly, it's just that I had other conditions and parentheses weren't set correctly. *errare humanum est*.

Comment: If so, please CLOSE the question -- it is misleading and time consuming for other people.

Comment: I closed the question as "no longer relevant", if you don't mind.

Comment: doesn't `group/msg[not(@owner) or @otherAttribute="true"]` worked for you?

Comment: ***For complete and correct answer*** without the distraction of the false alert raised by this question,  see [**XPath for elements with attribute not equal or does not exist**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632699/xpath-for-elements-with-attribute-not-equal-or-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 17):

In some old and not very standard XPath engine I had to use `string-length(@attr)=0` for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me when testing with [XPath Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xpe) (based on [Jaxen](http://jaxen.org/) library).
So I guess it is indeed depending on the XPath implementation.

Comment: Yes, I learned a trick on XPath, at least... :-)