# xpath query to select element where attribute not present

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

What should be xpath query to select an element where the attribute att not present.

```
<root>
  <elem att='the value' />
  <elem att='the value' />
  <elem att='the value' />
  **<elem />**
  <elem att='the value' />
  <elem att='the value' />
</root>
```

I want to update element where attribute att not present.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362945/xpath-query-to-select-node-when-attribute-does-not-exist?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

You can use `[@att]` to test for the *presence* of an attribute, so you just need:

```
//elem[not(@att)]
```

... to test for the *absence* of it.

([Tested using xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ffebb9f63955be9ae0d41c98eab6c3db))

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `@*` (the [abbreviated form](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#abbrev) of `attribute::*`) to represent any attribute.

With any attribute example:

```
//elem[@*]
```

Without any attribute example:

```
//elem[not(@*)]
```