# XPath for elements with attribute not equal or does not exist

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML format:

```
<test>
 <table>
   <rows>
     <row ID = "1" Name ="A"/>
     <row ID = "2" SubID = "1" Name ="B"/>
     <row ID = "3" Name ="C"/>
     <row ID = "4" SubID = "1" Name ="D"/>
     <row ID = "5" Name ="E"/>
     <row ID = "4" SubID = "2" Name ="E"/>
   </rows>
   .
   .
 </table>
</test>
```

I would like to take all the rows except the ones that do have `SubID = 1`.

**The hard part of this, is that not all the rows have attribute called `SubID`, and that not all the rows with the attribute `SubID`, have same value**.

The ideal output should be:

```
<row ID = "1" Name ="A"/>
<row ID = "3" Name ="C"/>
<row ID = "5" Name ="E"/>
<row ID = "4" SubID = "2" Name ="E"/>
```

I have tried to use an XPath with negation on value, but this won't work:

```
/test/table/row/not(@SubID=1)
```

Any help?

Comment: `/test/table/rows/row[not(@SubID=1)]`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Predicates

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**The "hard part" is actually easy:** A basic

*element*`[not(@`*attribute*`= '`*value*`')]`

predicate will **exclude** *elements* without the *attribute* **and** *elements* for which *attribute* equals *value*.

So, in your specific case, all `row` elements that do not have `@SubID` equal to `1`:

```
/test/table/rows/row[not(@SubID = '1')]
```

selects

```
<row ID="1" Name="A"/>
<row ID="3" Name="C"/>
<row ID="5" Name="E"/>
<row ID="4" Name="E" SubID="2"/>
```

as requested.